# How to add more text to a file by php

Tags: php

Hello guys the following code will add only one line of text to my 'file.txt' whenever i m

going to add more text so its replacing the old one, i want to have the old one with new also

Beside this one i want to separate the words in my 'txt.file' by a comma and space.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$Fname = $_POST['fname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$Phone = $_POST['number'];
$date = $_POST['date'];

$my_file = 'file.txt';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);

fwrite($handle, $Fname);
fwrite($handle, $email);
fwrite($handle, $Phone);
fwrite($handle, $date);

?>
```

Comment: Look at the `mode` section in the [documentation](http://au1.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) - it is very clear how to achieve what you're after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are using write mode (`w`). To add lines to the end, you have to append (`a`):

```
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'a');
```

To separate words by comma and space, join it into one string in PHP and than save it:

```
$finalString = $Fname . ', ' . $email . ', ' . $Phone . ', ' . $date;
fwrite($handle, $finalString );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//or you can use file_put_content to add to end of each line

$my_file = 'file.txt';

file_put_content($my_file, $Fname, PHP_EOL, PHP_APPEND);
file_put_content($my_file, $emai, PHP_EOL, PHP_APPEND);
file_put_content($my_file, $phone, PHP_EOL, PHP_APPEND);
```